# DLL administration

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll

I build some dlls to be used in a big application, and have a team working in the dlls heart of the application and another team working in the GUI, but I am having a problems in the deployment of the dll's when a change is done, because the GUI team needs or copy the new dll to the project folder, or delete the old reference and add the new one.  Is there a best practice to deal with this problem?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and developing in VB and C#

Thanks !!!

Comment: http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html
Subversion is a good product and it is free too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put everything in source control (binaries if you must) and have people rebase when they need the new functionality.

Comment: What is source control? ... is there some technique, software?
Thanks

Comment: See this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control to understand what is source control. Shortly, this is a software system the manages versions of your code, documents and even binaries. Example of source control systems is SVN, TFS, Git and Mercurial.

Comment: Ikaso - you didn't mention Source Safe...oh wait, you meant Source Control...nevermind.